# Почему при наведении на ссылки смещается меню?

Tags: css3

Когда я навожу мышкой на ссылки и они становятся выделенными, все меню начинает сдвигаться примерно на 1-3px. Помогите решить проблему

```
.nav{
position: absolute;
left: 20.3%;
top:8%;
}

.nav a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

.nav a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
background: white; /* Цвет фона */
border: 4px solid white;
color: black; /* Цвет текста */
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 30px; /* Уголки */
}

.nav li{
display: inline;
font-family: Bahnschrift;
font-size: 35px;
list-style-type: none;
color: white;
padding: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у ваших ссылок нет border в обычном состоянии

```
.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

А при наведении есть

```
.nav a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: white; /* Цвет фона */
    border: 4px solid white; /* <---- border 4px */
    color: black; /* Цвет текста */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 30px; /* Уголки */
}
```

Если этот эффект при наведении нужно сохранить, добавьте ссылкам невдимые отступы, вот так:

```
.nav a {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего из за вот этой строки:

```
border: 4px solid white;
```

Попробуйте поставить `0px`